# Create JSON from database query rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, d3.js

I want to create a forced layout diagram of my rails application data as [here in d3](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4062045)

I have a rails application with tables as per the diagram below:

[image]

I would like to create an expression in the controller that can output JSON in the required format which is:

```
{
  "user":[
    {"name":"Myriel"},
    {"name":"Napoleon"},
    {"name":"Mlle.Baptistine"}
  ],
  "relationship":[
    {"source":1,"target":0},
    {"source":2,"target":0},
    {"source":3,"target":0}
 ]
}
```

I guess this would involve a query in the controller- something like:

```
class GraphController < ApplicationController
  def data
  render :json =>  User.select('name')
  render :json =>  Relationship.select('follower_id') & Relationship.select('followed_id') 
  end
end
```

but then how do I combine the json output into one as per the example above? and also how to I rename the output so that follower_id becomes source and followed_id becomes target?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have quite a few options:

1. You can construct the appropriate structure and and then pass it to `render`, just like this:

   ```
   render json: {
     user: User.select('name')].map { |u|
       { name: u.name }
     },
     relationship: Relationship.select(:follower_id, :followed_id).map { |r|
       { source: r.follower_id, target: r.followed_id }
     }
   }
   ```
2. The former approach works, but it can become pretty complex. At this point you probably should think of making JSON rendering go via a separate view layer. It can be anything you like:

   - ERB, which is quite exotic, that I've never seen it in the wild, but still quite viable; you should be able to name your template like `show.json.erb` and go from there
   - A separate class that will build structures like in option no. 1 to be rendered in JSON, a sort of presenter
   - ... And finally, which seems the most appropriate to me, some JSON-specific rendering engine: RABL, JBuilder or whatever, there's a whole bunch out there

However, it should not be understated that rendering JSON from a controller like this is considered a bad smell. Having view code in a controller goes against MVC, which is Rails based on.

That leaves us with a flavor of option #2, whatever matches the complexity of the task at hand (according to your own gut feeling).

Hope this helps!

Comment: OK Thanks that's helpful. JBuilder looks easy to use. The only thing I dont get is how to actually then refer to the json Jbuilder has created. It doesnt create a physical file so when I'm trying to use it for example in an ajax call what so I refer to it as?

Comment: I might not really understand you 100%, but... It's pretty much like any other view engine in Rails. It is invoked as a part Rails controller action. So the result by default is written directly to the response stream. Just the same way it happens with "ERB (HAML/SLIM/whatever) to HTML" stuff.